# aggregation queries in mysql with indexing and partiton

Tags: mysql, indexing, relational-database, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a table with about 2 million rows as of now. The table is going to keep growing as about 0.5-06 million rows will be added each month.

I have for example a query as follows:

```
select `importer_name`, ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) AS top15_usd
from   `importer_bills`
WHERE  year(bill_of_entry_date)=2020
AND 
Month(bill_of_entry_date)=3
group  by `importer_name`
order  by ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) desc limit 15 offset 0;
```

This query currently takes `9.98` seconds to execute.

Follows the output of `explain`:

```
1   SIMPLE  importer_bills  p0  ref idx_importer_bills_upwork_09,idx_importer_bills_year_month  idx_importer_bills_year_month   5   const,const 1106762 100.00  Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

1. idx_importer_bills_upwork_09 is an index on `importer_name` column.
2. idx_importer_bills_year_month is an index on `bill_of_entry_year` and `bill_of_entry_month`

I have also added a partition by `bill_of_entry_year`.

I tried replacing the above query with:

```
select `importer_name`, ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) AS top15_usd
from   `importer_bills`
WHERE  
bill_of_entry_year=2020
AND
bill_of_entry_month = 3
group  by `importer_name`
order  by ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) desc limit 15 offset 0;
```

This took `9.01` seconds.

the output of `explain`:

```
1   SIMPLE  importer_bills  p0  ref idx_importer_bills_upwork_09,idx_importer_bills_year_month  idx_importer_bills_year_month   5   const,const 1106762 100.00  Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

How have a bunch of these queries based on even more filters than just year and month? Sometimes only with a year filter. 10 seconds for just 2M rows isn't acceptable. how can I go about optimizing this?

**The columns used in where clause is always going to change based on user selection of filters** but can consider making YEAR filter mandatory. May be month as well (but wouldn't;t ideally want to do it)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by rewriting the date filter in the `where` clause as a SARGable expression:

```
where bill_of_entry_date >= '2020-03-01' and bill_of_entry_date < '2020-04-01'
```

This does not uses date functions on the date column, so it may take advantage of an index. Then, I would recommend the following index:

```
importer_bills(bill_of_entry_year, importer_name, total_value_usd_exchange)
```

The first index column matches the `where` predicate; the following column matches the `group by` column, and the third is the aggregated column. It is not guaranteed that MySQL will use all columns in the index, but, if the `where` predicate is selective enough, you should still see a performance benefit.

Comment: The columns used in where clauses is always going to change based on user selection of filters but can consider making YEAR filter mandatory.  May be month as well (but wouldn't;t ideally want to do it)

Comment: @Simrankaur: you want to generate literal dates that correspond to the user input, rather than using date functions on the table columns - as shown in the exemple. Otherwise, the query will be inefficient.

Comment: Right. I do have bill_of_entry_year , bill_of_entry_month column on the table as well which I have tried using and added results of in the question